# Using BeanUtils.copyProperties from a Mybatis created object to a Spring Bean, the properties are null in the Spring bean. Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis

The problem I am encountering is that I have a class that looks something like this

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class TableModel{

    private Integer tableField1;

    ...
    //other properties, getters and setters here

}
```

Mybatis returns results from queries mapped to this object, and I wish to copy the result from this object to my Spring bean in a different class, like so:

```
public class MyClass {

      TableModel model

      @Autowired
      MyClass(TableModel model) {
           this.model = model;
           //...
      }

      //some code

      TableModel result = MyMapperInterface.selectFromTable();
      //Here, result.tableField1 is not 0 or null

      BeanUtils.copyProperties(result, model);

      //After copyProperties(), model.tableField1 is still null
      //...     

}
```

However, after the `BeanUtils.copyProperties()` call, the properties in `model` are still null. I double checked, and I am **not** using the Apache Commons version of copyProperties, I am using the Spring version of BeanUtils. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestScope` means that you get a different instance for every request. Semantically, this does not match with passing it as a constructor parameter (meaning it's shared for all users of that bean).

Even so, Spring will try to make that work for you by injecting a *proxy* for your `TableModel` that will magically switch it around depending on the request context. What's probably happening is that your underlying instance is not the same.

Avoid request-scoped beans generally. Don't use injection for per-request data; use method parameters instead. (And I suggest using MapStruct instead of BeanUtils, as it's both faster and safer.)